# Design of experiments (DOE) using factors with uneven levels

Tags: experiment-design

I have 2 modes, 3 different temperatures, 5 different pressures, and 6 different sample compositions. That's 2 X 3 X 5 X 6 = 180 total experiments. I'd like to use a response surface methodology (central composite design, or Box-Behnken) or some other appropriate technique to reduce the total number of experiments? The problem is, I don't believe these approaches allow for uneven amounts of levels for different factors, or as in the central composite design that automatically uses 5 levels for each factor. I don't have 5 levels for each factor, I have 2, 3, 5, and 6 levels. How then can I do this?

Comment: A full factorial would be $3\times 5 \times 6=90$ total runs (you say 180, why?) How many runs can you do? You could find some fraction by using D-optimality.

Comment: You are right, but I forgot another factor (called mode) with 2 levels, which brings it to 180. Ideally 50-75 runs at the end. I've heard of D-optimality but never learned about it yet.

Comment: Can you please add this information to the original post?

Comment: Temperature and pressure will be continuous, and mode is a categorical variable, yes?  What are the 6 different sample compositions?  You might be looking at a mixture experiment rather than a typical factorial-like DOE.  Are you sure that all four factors have practical-sized effects on your outcome variable(s) over the range you intend to vary them?

Answer (score 1):

Your post misses some essential information, such as the nature of the variables and the goal of the experiment. But one approach you can try is to first generate the full factorial design, and then choose some fraction by D-optimality.

D-optimality is implemented in R in the package `AlgDesign` and certainly many other places. On this site you can find some examples [in this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=AlgDesign+answers%3A1).